# Why does concatenation of lists take O(n)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, complexity-theory, algebraic-data-types

According to the theory of ADTs (Algebraic Data Types) the concatenation of two lists has to take `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the first list. You, basically, have to recursively iterate through the first list until you find the end.

From a different point of view, one can argue that the second list can simply be linked to the last element of the first. This would take constant time, if the end of the first list is known.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Because you need to make a copy of the left-hand argument (because lists are immutable in Haskell).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth no, lists are linked.

Comment: Based on this argument, inserting an element at the beginning of the list would also take O(n), since this would also imply duplicating the list.

Comment: @josejuan: Indeed, but that doesn't avoid the need to copy.  If I do `a + b` (sorry, I forget Haskell syntax), then I can't modify `a`, so I can't link it to `b`.  Instead, I need to create a copy of `a`, and link *that* to `b`.

Comment: @RaduStoenescu: Consider the graph that gets created; you only need to copy the left-hand argument.

Comment: Yes, I understand that lists in Haskell, as well as in other functional languages, are not only immutable, but also persistent data structures. I would like some guidance towards a more 'formal' argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of immutable state. A list is an object + a pointer, so if we imagined a list as a Tuple it might look like this:

```
let tupleList = ("a", ("b", ("c", [])))
```

Now let's get the first item in this "list" with a "head" function. This head function takes O(1) time because we can use fst:

```
> fst tupleList
```

If we want to swap out the first item in the list with a different one we could do this:

```
let tupleList2 = ("x",snd tupleList)
```

Which can also be done in O(1). Why? Because absolutely no other element in the list stores a reference to the first entry. Because of immutable state, we now have two lists, `tupleList` and `tupleList2`. When we made `tupleList2` we didn't copy the **whole** list. Because the original pointers are immutable we can continue to reference them but use something else at the start of our list.

Now let's try to get the last element of our 3 item list:

```
> snd . snd $ fst tupleList
```

That happened in O(3), which is equal to the length of our list i.e. O(n).

But couldn't we store a pointer to the last element in the list and access that in O(1)? To do that we would need an array, not a list. An array allows O(1) lookup time of any element as it is a primitive data structure implemented on a register level.

(ASIDE: If you're unsure of why we would use a Linked List instead of an Array then you should do some more reading about data structures, algorithms on data structures and Big-O time complexity of various operations like get, poll, insert, delete, sort, etc).

Now that we've established that, let's look at concatenation. Let's concat `tupleList` with a new list, `("e", ("f", []))`. To do this we have to traverse the whole list just like getting the last element:

```
tupleList3 = (fst tupleList, (snd $ fst tupleList, (snd . snd $ fst tupleList, ("e", ("f", [])))
```

The above operation is actually **worse** than O(n) time, because for each element in the list we have to re-read the list up to that index. But if we ignore that for a moment and focus on the key aspect: in order to get to the last element in the list, we must traverse the entire structure.

You may be asking, why don't we just store in memory what the last list item is? That way appending to the end of the list would be done in O(1). But not so fast, we can't change the last list item without changing the entire list. Why?

Let's take a stab at how that might look:

```
data Queue a = Queue { last :: Queue a, head :: a, next :: Queue a} | Empty
appendEnd :: a -> Queue a -> Queue a
appendEnd a2 (Queue l, h, n) = ????
```

IF I modify "last", which is an immutable variable, I won't actually be modifying the pointer for the last item in the queue. I will be creating a copy of the last item. Everything else that referenced that original item, will continue referencing the original item.

So in order to update the last item in the queue, I have to update everything that has a reference to it. Which can only be done in optimally O(n) time.

So in our traditional list, we have our final item:

```
List a []
```

But if we want to change it, we make a copy of it. Now the second last item has a reference to an old version. So we need to update that item.

```
List a (List a [])
```

But if we update the second last item we make a copy of it. Now the third last item has an old reference. So we need to update that. Repeat until we get to the head of the list. And we come full circle. Nothing keeps a reference to the head of the list so editing that takes O(1).

This is the reason that Haskell doesn't have Doubly Linked Lists. It's also why a "Queue" (or at least a FIFO queue) can't be implemented in a traditional way. Making a Queue in Haskell involves some serious re-thinking of traditional data structures.

If you become even more curious about how all of this works, consider getting the book [Purely Funtional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504).

EDIT: If you've ever seen this: http://visualgo.net/list.html you might notice that in the visualization "Insert Tail" happens in O(1). But in order to do that we need to modify the final entry in the list to give it a new pointer. Updating a pointer mutates state which is not allowed in a purely functional language. Hopefully that was made clear with the rest of my post.

Comment: A lot of algorithms that typically require a queue can still be implemented in a straightforward way in Haskell thanks to tying the knot.

Answer (score 6):

Operationally, an Haskell list is typically represented by a pointer to the first cell of a single-linked list (roughly). In this way, `tail` just returns the pointer to the next cell (it does not have to copy anything), and consing `x :` in front of the list allocates a new cell, makes it point to the old list, and returns the new pointer. The list accessed by the old pointer is unchanged, so there's no need to copy it.

If you instead append a value with `++ [x]`, then you can not modify the original liked list by changing its last pointer unless you know that the original list will never be accessed. More concretely, consider

```
x = [1..5]
n = length (x ++ [6]) + length x
```

If you modify `x` when doing `x++[6]`, the value of `n` would turn up to be 12, which is wrong. The last `x` refer to the unchanged list which has length `5`, so the result of `n` must be 11.

Practically, you can't expect the compiler to optimize this, even in those cases in which `x` is no longer used and it could, theoretically, be updated in place (a "linear" use). What happens is that the evaluation of `x++[6]` must be ready for the worst-case in which `x` is reused afterwards, and so it must copy the whole list `x`.

As @Ben notes, saying "the list is copied" is imprecise. What actually happens is that the cells with the pointers are copied (the so-called "spine" on the list), but the elements are not. For instance,

```
x = [[1,2],[2,3]]
y = x ++ [[3,4]]
```

requires only to allocate `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]` *once*. The lists of lists `x,y` will share pointers to the lists of integers, which do not have to be duplicated.

Comment: Although it only needs to copy the *list cells themselves*. The items stored in the list are typically pointers to other data structures, which can be perfectly well shared between the original and new list.

Comment: What I'd really like to see, personally, is a clear explanation of why lazy-spined lists are incompatible with `o(n)` append.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is related to a question I wrote for TCS Stackexchange some time back: the data structure that supports constant-time concatenation of functional lists is a [difference list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/difference-lists-in-functional-programming).

A way of handling such lists in a functional programming language was worked out by [Yasuhiko Minamide in the 90s](http://www.score.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~minamide/papers/hole.popl98.pdf); I effectively [rediscovered it](http://requestforlogic.blogspot.com/search/label/holey%20data) a while back. However, the good run-time guarantees require language-level support that's not available in Haskell.

Comment: Yasuhiko Minamide's data structures with holes seem somewhat similar in spirit to Huet's [zippers](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf) (JFP 97), but the zippers are purely functional, while the structures with holes seem more useful for doing, in a call-by-value language, things that are very natural in a call-by-need language.

Comment: Difference lists are functions `[a] -> [a]` built up by composing values of `\x -> (x:)`. Such functions can be represented as simple unbalanced leaf trees, as shown in [an old post](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2442) on cstheory.SE.

Comment: They are, in fact, similar, but Yasuhiko Minamide's structures have different asymptotic complexity, as that CSTheory post (which was an answer to a question I asked :)) describes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate two lists (call them `xs` and `ys`), we need to modify the final node in `xs` in order to link it to (i.e. point at) the first node of `ys`.

But Haskell lists are immutable, so we have to create a copy of `xs` first.  This operation is `O(n)` (where `n` is the length of `xs`).

Example:

```
xs
|
v
1 -> 2 -> 3

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
^              ^
|              |
xs ++ ys       ys
```

Comment: Whether we have to "create a copy of `xs`" or not is an operational detail. The algorithm is O(n) because we must traverse all `n` elements of the left-hand list.

Comment: @jberryman, that becomes less of an operational detail if you represent a list using something like `data List a = List {theListItself::[a], theLastCons::[a]}`.